# Remove white background from tag shape built in CSS

Tags: html, css, tags, shapes

I've come across and modified an interesting snippet of code that makes links looks like tags. The problem is that the shape is only visible properly when the background is white. The moment I change the background, the shape turns rectangular and spoils the look.

Please have a look at the code snippet and fiddle example for a better understanding.

```css
body {
  font: 12px/1.5 'PT Sans', serif;
  margin: 25px;
  background: blue; /*the moment background is white, it's ok*/
}

.tags {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden; 
  padding: 0;
}

.tags li {
  float: left; 
}

.tag {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  color: #999;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 26px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 23px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
}

.tag::before {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  content: '';
  height: 6px;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  top: 10px;
}

.tag::after {
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #eee;
  border-top: 13px solid transparent;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.tag:hover {
  background-color: crimson;
  color: white;
}

.tag:hover::after {
   border-left-color: crimson; 
}
```

```html
<h2>Example 2</h2>
<ul class="tags">
  <li><a href="#" class="tag">HTML</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tag">CSS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tag">JavaScript</a></li>
</ul>
```

In the code above, the moment you change `background` to white in the 4th line of CSS, it works fine.

How do I get this to run on all background colors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change css to this:

```css
    body {
      font: 12px/1.5 'PT Sans', serif;
      margin: 25px;
      background: blue; /*the moment background is white, it's ok*/
    }
    
    .tags {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden; 
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .tags li {
      float: left; 
    }
    
    .tag {
      background: #eee;
      border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
      color: #999;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 26px;
      line-height: 26px;
      padding: 0 20px 0 23px;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 20px 10px 0;
      text-decoration: none;
      -webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
    }
    
    .tag::before {
      background: #fff;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      content: '';
      height: 6px;
      left: 10px;
      position: absolute;
      width: 6px;
      top: 10px;
    }
    
    .tag::after {
      background: transparent;
      border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
      border-left: 10px solid #eee;
      border-top: 13px solid transparent;
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      right: -10px;
      top: 0;
    }
    
    .tag:hover {
      background-color: crimson;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .tag:hover::after {
       border-left-color: crimson; 
    }
```

```html
<h2>Example 2</h2>
<ul class="tags">
  <li><a href="#" class="tag">HTML</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tag">CSS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tag">JavaScript</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks. Could you explain the change you made though? I'll accept the answer

Comment: .tag::after has a background set to white color. it is displaying only css triangle which color is defined in border-color, so we needed to set this background to transparent. Then it was contained inside the tag, so I set the higher margin-right to the tag and place the triangle outside the tag.

Comment: Cool. Is there anyway we can get that small circle in the tag to be transparent as well? In the sense we can see the background through it. I tried changing stuff but didn't work out

Comment: as it is over the tag: you can only set the background-color to the same as the body backgound. in .tag::before

Comment: Could you change it in the fiddle? I'm not quite sure what you're saying

Comment: see another answer .tag::before - background value

Answer (score 1):

```css
    body {
      font: 12px/1.5 'PT Sans', serif;
      margin: 25px;
      background: blue; /*the moment background is white, it's ok*/
    }
    
    .tags {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden; 
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .tags li {
      float: left; 
    }
    
    .tag {
      background: #eee;
      border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
      color: #999;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 26px;
      line-height: 26px;
      padding: 0 20px 0 23px;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 20px 10px 0;
      text-decoration: none;
      -webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
    }
    
    .tag::before {
      background: blue;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      content: '';
      height: 6px;
      left: 10px;
      position: absolute;
      width: 6px;
      top: 10px;
    }
    
    .tag::after {
      background: transparent;
      border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
      border-left: 10px solid #eee;
      border-top: 13px solid transparent;
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      right: -10px;
      top: 0;
    }
    
    .tag:hover {
      background-color: crimson;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .tag:hover::after {
       border-left-color: crimson; 
    }
```

```html
<h2>Example 2</h2>
<ul class="tags">
  <li><a href="#" class="tag">HTML</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tag">CSS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tag">JavaScript</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks again!